# URL format for accessing Images from Back End Server

Tags: angular, image

currently I'm using `[attr.src]="selectedUser.image"` (images are saved in 'uploads' folder over nodejs server (localhost:3000))

Angular converts path `(localhost:3000/uploads/abc.jpg)` to `(localhost:4200/uploads/abc.jpg)` so I'm getting error of 404 of not finding image.

Can anyone please suggest me to secure server path so that it'll not get converted in angular server path?

Comment: How you are giving the value of selectedUser.image?

Comment: I got it done. just stored the server path i.e localhost:3000 in a constant and append before image name by interpolation. it works for me.

Comment: You can rename image in back end and then save it to a specific folder. After that you can directly use global variable+image ID(name) so image will be fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should store url of backend in a separate variable, like this:

in ts:

```
let backendUrl = 'http://localhost'
let imgUrl = '/uploads/abc.jpg'
```

in html:

```
attr.src="{{backendUrl}}{{imgUrl}}"
```